# Four Minim in Kaballah

Tags: sources-mekorot, mysticism-kabbalah, sukkot

In my Siddur it says in the 'Yehi Ratzon' before the Netilat Lulav, that by combining the 4 Minim I ask Hashem to combine the 4 letters of his holy name.

Does anybody know, which Min corrsponds to which letter?

Maybe more reading material concerning this topic ?

Comment: I literally quote my Siddur. Calm down.

Comment: Sorry, you're 100% right. I saw a few other wacky questions and answers and I guess just went on a stampede and let my judgement be clouded - I think I just saw the Kaballaj-mysticism and posted it. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: Though, I do recommend that R' Aharon Lopiansky Q & A (and all the other ones, and all his content) - I just found out that he has a website with tons of recordings, its great.

Answer (score 5):

As per the Arizal in the Pri Eitz Chaim at [the beginning of Shaar Lulav v'Daled Minim](https://www.sefaria.org/Pri_Etz_Chaim,_Gate_of_Lulav_1.3) and Shaar Hakavanos [Inyan Sukkos Drush 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Sha%27ar_HaKavanot,_Sermons_on_the_Festival_of_Sukkot_5.3), the hadasim are the yud, the aravos are the first hei, the lulav is the vav, and the esrog is the second hei.